# Right-click event handler to CanvasJS Charts' dataPoints?

Tags: canvasjs

Can you add a right-click event handler to CanvasJS Charts' dataPoints?

I'm aware the documentation mentions "click, mouseover, mouseout and mousemove" as available events, so I'm looking for an undocumented feature or a trick to accomplish this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can have a trick for working with right click also. Follow, [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/canvasjs/c3erb9c5/)-

```
//Work aroound for right click on data points
var chartContainer = document.getElementById("chartContainenter"); 
function onMouseover(e){
        chartContainer.addEventListener('contextmenu', e.chart.rightClick = function(ev){
            ev.preventDefault();
            onRightClick(e); //right click event handler
            return false;
    }, false);
}

function onMouseout(e){
        chartContainer.removeEventListener('contextmenu', e.chart.rightClick);
    document.getElementById("textBox").innerHTML = "";
}
```